# Aggregating on dictionaries in nest ElasticSearch

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

So I have a set of indexed products that contains a dictionary with a single key and a list of values, with which I'm trying to build a facetted search. However I am very much an elastic newbie.

```
    Product Product {
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> Properties
    //extra fields removed for simplicity
    }
```

where properties may be something along the lines of

```
["Color":["Blue","Yellow","Red"],"Size":["Small","Medium","Large"]
```

or

```
["Material":["Wood"], "Shape":["Circle","Square"], "Size":["Tiny","Medium","Large","Huge"]
```

I'm looking to write a couple of aggregations, which will return the keys, and the values of those keys.
I.e if the examples above were to be indexed, the first aggregation would return a bucket containing `"Color","Size","Material","Shape"`

and the second aggregation would return 4 buckets, each with the unique values for each key.
i.e `Size:["Tiny","small","medium","large","huge"]`
etc

I realize I need a nested aggregation for this, however none of my attempts are bringing back anything in the buckets. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Here's what I have so far.

```
    var ProductsQuery = client.Search<Product>(s => s
        .Index("products")
        .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Nested("properties", n => n
                .Path(p => p.Properties.Suffix("keyword"))
                    .Aggregations(a => a
                        .Terms("property-keys", t => t
                            .Field(f => f.Properties.Keys.Suffix("keyword"))))));
```

Edit for some requested details:

The current properties mapping (It appears to be creating a new mapping for every Key which I'm not sure if that's typical or not?) I haven't put the whole object mapping here as it's rather huge. Products have a lot of fields:

```
"properties" : {
  "properties" : {
    "Colour" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Equipment" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Football Age" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Football Size" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Frame Weight" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Garment" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Head Shape" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Level" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Product" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Size" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Sport" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Surface" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Type" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Unit" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Weight" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "comparer" : {
      "type" : "object"
    },
    "count" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    },
    "item" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "keys" : {
      "properties" : {
        "count" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "values" : {
      "properties" : {
        "count" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and some indexed documents

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134550",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Type" : [
          "Sleds"
        ],
        "Product" : [
          "Sleds"
        ],
        "Colour" : [
          "Black"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134566",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Sport" : [
          "Fitness"
        ],
        "Type" : [
          "Corner",
          "Edge",
          "Middle"
        ],
        "Size" : [
          "10mm",
          "15mm",
          "20mm"
        ],
        "Product" : [
          "Floor Matting"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134576",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Sport" : [
          "Rugby"
        ],
        "Type" : [
          "Skills Training"
        ],
        "Equipment" : [
          "Rugby Balls"
        ],
        "Size" : [
          "4",
          "5"
        ],
        "Level" : [
          "Skills"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134579",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Sport" : [
          "Rugby"
        ],
        "Type" : [
          "Match Union"
        ],
        "Equipment" : [
          "Rugby Balls"
        ],
        "Size" : [
          "4",
          "5"
        ],
        "Level" : [
          "Club",
          " School"
        ],
        "Unit" : [
          "12 Pack",
          "Each"
        ],
        "Colour" : [
          "Blue",
          "Red",
          "White"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134600",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Sport" : [
          "Rugby"
        ],
        "Size" : [
          "Large",
          "Medium",
          "Small",
          "X/Large",
          "X/Small",
          "XX/Small",
          "XXX/Small"
        ],
        "Garment" : [
          "Gloves"
        ],
        "Colour" : [
          "Red"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134601",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Sport" : [
          "Netball"
        ],
        "Size" : [
          "Large",
          "X/Large",
          "X/Small",
          "XX/Small",
          "XXX/Small"
        ],
        "Garment" : [
          "Gloves"
        ],
        "Colour" : [
          "Red"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134609",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Sport" : [
          "Netball"
        ],
        "Size" : [
          "Large",
          "Medium",
          "Small",
          "X/Large",
          "X/Small",
          "XXX/Small"
        ],
        "Garment" : [
          "Gloves"
        ],
        "Colour" : [
          "Black",
          "Green"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134617",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Sport" : [
          "Football"
        ],
        "Type" : [
          "Training"
        ],
        "Football Size" : [
          "2"
        ],
        "Equipment" : [
          "Footballs"
        ],
        "Size" : [
          "4",
          "5"
        ],
        "Unit" : [
          "12 Pack",
          "Each"
        ],
        "Weight" : [
          "290",
          "360"
        ],
        "Surface" : [
          "Grass",
          " Astroturf"
        ],
        "Football Age" : [
          "9-14 years",
          " 14+ years"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134548",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Type" : [
          "Sleds"
        ],
        "Product" : [
          "Sleds"
        ],
        "Colour" : [
          "Black",
          "Grey"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "products-20-01-2021-13-49-08",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "134558",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Sport" : [
          "Squash"
        ],
        "Equipment" : [
          "Squash Rackets"
        ],
        "Size" : [
          "27\""
        ],
        "Head Shape" : [
          "Bridged Closed Throat"
        ],
        "Frame Weight" : [
          "Over 160g"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Mind sharing the index mapping too? Maybe a couple of actual docs and not just "something along the lines of" :)

Comment: @JoeSorocin Hey Joe, thanks for taking interest, I've added the mapping for the properties field, and a few documents in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, in order to obtain these buckets you could say with Query DSL the following:

```
POST products-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_Colour": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "properties.Colour.keyword"
      }
    },
    "by_Size": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "properties.Size.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which would then need to be translated into the NEST code -- and I'm sure there are plenty of examples out there.

---

But your observation was correct -- ES created lots of mappings automatically.
I'd advise against the current data format and rather go with:

```
{
  "properties": [
    {
      "key": "Type",
      "values": ["Sleds"]
    },
    {
      "key": "Product",
      "values": ["Sleds"]
    },
    {
      "key": "Colour",
      "values": ["Black"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and making `properties` of type `nested`.

That way you'll query on shared paths `properties.key` and aggregate on `properties.values.keyword`.

Keep in mind that `nested` field types need their own, actual [`nested` mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) -- you cannot use nested queries without the proper mappings.

Check this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65581838/8160318) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690886/8160318) for more context.

Comment: Glad I could help. Btw — I’m putting together an Elasticsearch handbook and some of the chapters deal with nested fields in more detail. I think the whole thing would be beneficial to you as you’re starting off with ES. [Let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) what exactly you’d like to learn about and I’ll let you know when the handboon it out. Thanks

Comment: Just implemented the suggestions in the related posts, and they're working beautifully. I'll be sure to keep an eye out for your book. Many thanks!

Comment: Wonderful! Don't forget to sign up at the link above 